# Import angular component in PhantomJS with jasmine/karma

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, phantomjs, karma-runner, html-imports

The following unit test works in Chrome (due to its native support for HTML-imports), but I'm struggling to get it to work with PhantomJS (and other browsers for that matter).

I'm trying to polyfill the import ('webcomponents.js/HTMLImports.min.js') but it doesn't have any effect.

karma.conf.js

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    plugins: [
      'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
      'karma-chrome-launcher',
      'karma-jasmine'
    ],
    files: [
      'node_modules/angular/angular.js',
      'node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'node_modules/webcomponents.js/HTMLImports.min.js',

      'component/so-example.html',

      'test/test.spec.js'
    ],
    port: 9876,
    browsers: ['Chrome', 'PhantomJS']
  });
};
```

component/so-example.html

```
<script>
(function () {
  var soExampleComponent = {
    transclude: true,
    bindings: {
      number: '@'
    },
    template: '<span class="compiled">{{$ctrl.number}}</span>'
  };

  angular.module('so.components.example', []).component('soExample', soExampleComponent);
})();
</script>
```

test/test.spec.js

```
describe('<so-example>', function () {
  var $scope, el;

  beforeEach(module('so.components.example'));

  beforeEach(inject(function ($compile, $rootScope) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    el = $compile('<so-example number="{{ 3 }}"></so-example>')($scope)[0];
    $scope.$digest();
  }));

  it('should import and compile', function () {
    expect(el.querySelector('.compiled').textContent).toBe('3');
  });
});
```

the error from PhantomJS

```
forEach@C:/Temp/so-example/node_modules/angular/angular.js:322:24
loadModules@C:/Temp/so-example/node_modules/angular/angular.js:4591:12
createInjector@C:/Temp/so-example/node_modules/angular/angular.js:4513:30
workFn@C:/Temp/so-example/node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:3060:60
C:/Temp/so-example/node_modules/angular/angular.js:4631:53
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'el.querySelector') in C:/Temp/so-example/test/test.spec.js (line 14)
C:/Temp/so-example/test/test.spec.js:14:14
```

Comment: Why is your component in an HTML file?

Comment: It allows me to collocate my styles and script together into a neat component (a la web-components) without introducing an unnecessary build step (concatenating them), I didn't include any styles, as I didn't feel it was relevant to the example.    
  
Although, as you might expect, if I pull it out into its own .js file it works as normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After banging my head against this for about a day, it turns out the solution was quite simple.

We can force `jasmine` to wait until the import has finished by having the following block execute before any tests which rely on an HTML import.

```
// Wait for the HTML Imports polyfill to finish before running anything else
beforeAll(function(done) {
  window.addEventListener('HTMLImportsLoaded', done);
});
```

I've put this into a separate file that is referenced in `karma.conf.js` before all of my other `spec.js` files.

However, it can be placed within a single `describe` block or a single `spec.js` if it isn't required anywhere else.